# How to register delegate implementation in DI container

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

If I have the following delagate:

```
public static class Services
{
    public delegate Task<bool> INameAvailable(string name);
}
```

How can I create an implementation that is able to search in a database in example with entity framework?

Let's say I have the following implementation:

```
public class NameCheckService
{
    private readonly MyContext _dbContext;

    public NameCheckService(MyContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public async Task<bool> IsNameAvailable(string name)
    {
        return await _dbContext.Names.AnyAsync(i => 
            i.Name.ToLowerInvariant() == name.ToLowerInvariant());
    }
}
```

How do I register this???

I can do this:

```
services.AddSingleton<Services.IsNameAvailable>((name) => new Task<bool>(true));
```

But how do I point it to the `NameCheckService` class?
So something like this:

```
services.AddScoped<Services.INameAvailable>(NameCheckService.IsNameAvailable);
```

The delegate will be a parameter of a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From pure technical standpoint - you can register the service and then use `Add{LifetimeScope}` overload which accepts `Func<IServiceProvider, TService>` delegate and resolve the required service there:

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<NameCheckService>();
services.AddScoped<Services.INameAvailable>(sp => 
    sp.GetRequiredService<NameCheckService>().IsNameAvailable);
```

Comment: Which using should I add to get the overload? I'm calling this from an IServiceCollection extension method. I already tried this but couldn't get the 'sp.GetRequiredService<NameCheckService>().IsNameAvailable' part working...

Comment: @LockTar it's [`ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.serviceproviderserviceextensions.getrequiredservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) but you can use `GetService` also.

Comment: Ok strange. I thought I did yesterday the same but apparantly not. It's working. Thanks!